# AngularJS loading Directives before completing Service http call

Tags: angularjs

I try to get the data from via http call from a service,  and, assign return data from the service to the controller’s variable $scope. fusionJsonObj and finally pass this data to the Directive to make it available under directives scope for further processing.

Issue :

Before http  call fetches data and assign it to the controllers $scope.fusionJsonObj, it went ahead and loaded Directive (at this point directive does not have data associated with  $scope.fusionJsonObj as promise on the service did not return data from the server http call.

In short, please help me loading service http and promise where it assign http data to the controllers  $scope.fusionJsonObj before loading Directive

Plunker link:
http://plnkr.co/edit/xGchsnw2u9LremFATfvY?p=preview

Controller as follows:

```
 angular.module('FundooDirectiveTutorial', [])
      .controller('FundooCtrl', function($scope, readFusionTblService, $window) {
          $scope.rating = 3; //total no of the column
        $scope.listItemIndex=2; //no of column-1    
        alert('## in the Controller - and calling service method on http call');

        var promise = readFusionTblService.getFusionData(); 
        alert('## in the Controller - and calling promise');

        promise.then(
                    function(dataReturn){
                        alert('## in the Controller -  with promise execution');    
                        $scope.fusionJsonObj = dataReturn;
```

service as follows:

```
  .service('readFusionTblService', function($http, $q){



        alert("### in the Service ");

        this.getFusionData = function(){
                            var deferred = $q.defer();
                            var urlQuery = "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%201n-NpyEkVKBOLSn_yE2LPL5Tk9K79saDkpKCrF00%20WHERE%20country='Sweden'%20AND%20type='glass'%20ORDER%20BY%20ST_DISTANCE(ComputedAddress,LATLNG(42,-83))%20LIMIT%2025&key=AIzaSyBqKyD7u_2CwBMQ3c9qAeMDTJaQIjYlgJo";

                            alert("### in the Service - before http call");                         
                            $http.get(urlQuery).success(function(data, status) {
                                    alert("### in the Service - After http call ####");                                 
                                    deferred.resolve(data);
                                }).error(function(data, status) {
                                    deferred.reject(data);
                                });                             
                            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Comment: Oh please replace `alert` with `console.log`

Comment: Replaced alters with consloe.log.  (alerts was to show call method sequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your directive functionality depends on `promise`. `promise.then` always return another promise. Keep the new promise and pass to the directive like

```
var newPromise =  promise.then(...);
$scope.ratingConfig = {
    myPromise: newPromise
};
```

In `HTML` pass the promise to the directive like

```
<div fundoo-rating rating-config="ratingConfig" row-item-index="listItemIndex" rating-value="rating" on-rating-selected="saveRatingToServer(rating, ratingTextVal)" item-data="billTblModel" ></div>
```

In directive wrap the promise depended functionality like

```
scope.ratingConfig.myPromise.then(function() {/*promise depended code*/});
```

Check the updated [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/b4XRrTRKyaj1BnmLBmzQ?p=preview)

Comment: Reza thanks reply. Being newbee need your help.
1) Before loading mainPage(id="mainPageId"),how to populate “rowDataArray”(hardcoded right now) from  $scope.fusionJsonObj.
2) Also on 2nd page (id="dashBoardPageId"), how to populate “billTblModel” (hardcoded right now)  from $scope.fusionJsonObj.
    In short $scope.fusionJsonObj will be a sort of globle data (via http call from service), then populate controllers $scope.variable  which will be passed to the Directive  before page load…

Comment: Reza, surprisingly newPromise is working. Please direct me if Im on right direction where I like to read http json data, store it into controllers $scope.fusionJSonObj and then carry out further processing.

Comment: `$http` it self return `promise` so when you are using `$http` you don't need `$q`. Also you can use angular `$resource` with `$q` if your server-side is `RESTful`, read more details http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

Comment: Thank for your reply. Being newbee, would like to be in touch with you email lgframeATyahooDOTcom, Naresh